# iPad mini 2 has encountered a problem while installing an update

Tags: ipad

My 9-year-old started an update on her new iPad mini 2. In the middle of the update she turned it off.

Now it comes on and shows the Apple logo. Then it switches over to a screen that shows the power supply cord with an iTunes music symbol directly above the picture of the cord. Any suggestions as to what I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: DFU mode: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5269891?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Your daughter's iPad mini isn't broken, but she will lose everything not stored in iCloud (contacts, documents, likely photos will all be alright).

In order to get the iPad back to normal you'll need to restore it with iTunes on your Mac or PC (it comes with OS X on a Mac, but will need to be downloaded from http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ if you don't already have it).

To paraphrase [this Apple Support link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252):

1. Plug the iPad into your computer by using the Lightning-to-USB cable
   included with it.
2. Open iTunes
3. Select the iPad in iTunes
4. Click "Restore" or "Restore from Backup" if you have one
5. The iPad will need to be set up as if it was just taken out of the box, but it will be running iOS 9.2, the newest update.